# Evento Mouse Enter, se aplica tambien a los hijos

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

Tengo este codigo en react, y espero que al pasar el mouse sobre una seccion, se ejecute la funcion `onMouseOver` que le paso por props al componente. Esta funcion solo imprime un console.log del `e.target`. La cosa es que si yo paso el mouse sobre la seccion, correctamente veo `<section id="amenities"... />`, pero si paso el mouse sobre algun elemento interno de esta section, ahora se consolea el elemento interno. Hay alguna forma de SIEMPRE obtener como `e.target` el `section` en lugar de sus elementos internos?

```
<section
  className="resort-amenities"
  id="amenities"
  onMouseEnter={onMouseOver}
 >
  <h2 className="title">Amenities</h2>
  <div className="amenities-wrapper">
    {renderAmenities}
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás usando [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

> ...que identifica el elemento en el que se produjo el evento.

De esta forma, al pasar el mouse sobre cualquier elemento dentro de tu `<section>` se delega el evento del padre a los hijos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es utilizar [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) que:

> Siempre hace referencia al elmento al cual el controlador del evento fue asociado...

Es decir, aunque el evento de pasar el mouse sobre tu elemento `<section>` ocurra sobre cualquier hijo del mismo, `currentTarget` siempre será el padre, es decir tu elemento `<section>`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.